# Why std::vector::push_back needs the assignment operator

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++03

```
std::vector::push_back(constT& value)
```

requires the type T to be CopyInsertable according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) .

However, compiling the following program with failes ([clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7291fa64aa42a851), GCC, Visual; both **without c++11**) unless I provide a public assignment operator.

```
#include <vector>

class A {
  A& operator= (const A& rhs); //private !! 
};

int main()  {
 std::vector<A> v;
 A a;
 v.push_back(a);
}
```

**Why do I need to provide this assignment operator, I was under the impression that the copy construct was enough.**

P.S. I could not find the place in the standard where this is defined, so if you could point to the reference, I would be most grateful

Comment: @Griwes your type has an accessible assignment operator. Not sure what you are showing.

Comment: unless i provide public assignment operator

Comment: @Griwes That's one way to read it. Another is that this code fails to compile (that is what OP actually says), and if they provide an *accessibe* assignment operator it compiles.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which have the error, and then show that in your question. Also please edit your question to also include the complete and unedited error log.

Comment: @ToBe To remove extra sources of confusion, could you make your assignment operator return an `A&`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is: C++03: http://ideone.com/0t6HFs

Comment: I put example ,ready to test here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7291fa64aa42a851

Comment: As you said, it needs a [CopyInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyInsertable) type, which is not assignment.

Comment: @PiotrS. No it doesn't. http://ideone.com/0t6HFs. People, please understand that OP is compiling in pre-C++11 mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [reference you quote](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) applies to C++11. However, the C++03 standard has stricter requirements on types that can be stored in containers:

> **23.1 Container requirements [lib.container.requirements]**
>
> ...
>
> The type of objects stored in these components must meet the
>   requirements of CopyConstructible types (20.1.3), and the additional
>   requirements of ***Assignable*** types.

(emphasis mine.) These requirements have been greatly relaxed in C++11, and are usually expressed in terms of the specific operations performed on containers. In that standard, your code would be valid, since the only requirement would be that `A` be `CopyInsertable`.

Comment: You cite the container requirements. Are there also requirements on a function level? For example, could push_back only require `CopyConstructable` even though the vector additionally requires assignability?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Not really, certainly not less restrictive requirements. But as I said in my answer, this all applies to C++03. In C++11, the requirements are per operation, and for OP's code the requirement would be that `A` be `CopyInsertable`.